User permissions inside Docker container
I'm trying to set up a Docker Laravel local working environment on Ubuntu 22.04.  I've never used Docker before and am using some provided scripts and instructions.  Unfortunately the project lead doesn't know anything about permissions in Docker containers, it has been working fine for him (Windows) and the other team member (Mac OS)
In a makefile we have
setup: ## Run the initial setup to get sail up and running
    docker run --rm \
    -u "$$(id -u):$$(id -g)" \
    -v "$$(pwd):/var/www/html" \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php82-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs

I understand this should setup the Docker container with a user that has the same permissions as the user that runs make setup ?
When I run it I get an error:
*In StreamHandler.php line 137:
The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be op
ened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The /var/www/html/bootstrap
/cache directory must be present and writable.
Context: {"exception":{}}
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
make: *** [Makefile:4: setup] Error 1
*
This looks like a permissions error to me?
To experiment I tried changing the setup command to:
setup: ## Run the initial setup to get sail up and running
    docker run --rm -it \
    -u "$$(id -u):$$(id -g)" \
    -v "$$(pwd):/var/www/html" \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php82-composer:latest \
    bash

When I use that...
I have no name!@b79c5795a93a:/var/www/html$ ls -l
total 1724
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    646 Jun  7 17:09 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   4158 May 14 21:26 README.md
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root 978060 May 14 21:26 _ide_helper.php
drwxrwxr-x  22 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 app
-rwxrwxr-x   1 root root   1686 May 14 21:26 artisan
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root     31 May 14 21:26 blade.format.json
drwxrwxr-x   3 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 bootstrap
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   5247 May 14 21:26 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root 479203 May 14 21:26 composer.lock
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 config
drwxrwxr-x   5 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 database
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   2390 May 14 21:26 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwxr-x   3 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 infrastructure
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    223 May 14 21:26 jsconfig.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root  18421 May 14 21:26 larastan-extension.neon
drwxr-xr-x 232 1000 1000  12288 Jun  7 16:39 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root 152339 Jun  7 16:39 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   1459 May 14 21:26 package.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    862 May 14 21:26 phpstan.neon
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   1131 May 14 21:26 phpunit.xml
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root     85 May 14 21:26 pint.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root     93 May 14 21:26 postcss.config.js
drwxrwxr-x   3 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 public
drwxrwxr-x   7 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 resources
drwxrwxr-x   5 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 resources_old
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 routes
drwxrwxr-x   6 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 storage
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 stubs
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   3124 May 14 21:26 tailwind.config.js
drwxrwxr-x   6 root root   4096 May 14 21:26 tests
drwxrwxr-x  73 root root   4096 May 15 09:46 vendor
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    931 May 14 21:26 vite.config.js
I have no name!@b79c5795a93a:/var/www/html$ groups
groups: cannot find name for group ID 1000
1000
I have no name!@b79c5795a93a:/var/www/html$ 

So:
Should I be a user called "I have no name!" that is a member of no groups?
If so,  do those file and folder permissions look like what is expected in a Docker Laravel setup?
Or, how can I setup the container with a user who can do what is needed?
I've probably missed some vital info, I'm so unfamiliar with this I don't even know what might be needed, please let me know!

There's an Ubuntu composer package which won't have any of these permission-related problems, and will let you just run composer install without the six lines before it.  Can you use that?

Thanks David but the link is broken
